# Consider words with equal capital and lowercase letters

Tags: r

I would like to make an adjustment to the code below. Note that I am averaging for Fridays and Thursdays. However, it is showing average for Thursday twice, this is because I have Thursday in capital letters and thursday in small letters in my database. However, I would like to make some adjustments that consider Thursday and thursday to be the same thing.

```
library(dplyr)

Test <- structure(list(date1 = as.Date(c("2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01")),
                       date2 = as.Date(c("2021-10-22","2021-10-22","2021-10-28","2021-10-30")),
                       Week = c("Friday", "Friday", "Thursday", "thursday"),
                       Category = c("FDE", "FDE", "FDE", "FDE"),
                       time = c(4, 6, 6, 3)), class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -4L))
    meanTest1 <- Test %>%
      group_by(Week,Category) %>%
      dplyr::summarize(mean(time))

> meanTest1
  Week     Category `mean(time)`
1 Friday   FDE                 5
2 thursday FDE                 3
3 Thursday FDE                 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need it to be title case, use `toTitleCase` from `tools`, or else convert to lower case (`tolower`) or upper case (`toupper`) for the 'Week' column and use that in `group_by`

```
library(dplyr)
Test %>%
    group_by(Week = tools::toTitleCase(Week), Category) %>% 
    summarise(time = mean(time, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  Week     Category  time
  <chr>    <chr>    <dbl>
1 Friday   FDE        5  
2 Thursday FDE        4.5
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. Just one question: There are any difference in `dplyr::summarize(mean(time))` to `summarise(time = mean(time, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')`?

Comment: @Antonio It is just to prevent the message in the output ``summarise()` has grouped output by 'Week'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.`.  I always use that, instead of the default option which drops the last grouping element.  The `na.rm = TRUE` is also useful when there are NA element in the column.  By default, it is `na.rm = FALSE` and if there are any NA, then `mean` returns `NA`

Comment: Yes @akrun, thanks! =)

Comment: about `na.rm=TRUE`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69857915/problem-using-na-rm-true-in-summarize-in-r-code

Comment: @Antonio Your function is not clear, so I posted a solution with the actual function that does Mode